# Find consecutive rows from n with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table with values:

```
val  
1
2
3
7
8
9
```

The table has also an id column, not relevant right now.

I want to insert one value, but the rule is there can't be any repeated values. Let's say I insert a new 2, the current 2 should become 3, and so on, up to the value 3, which will turn into 4. In this case, the values 7, 8 and 9 don't need to be 'moved'.

I'm working with **SQLite**. The insert or update part can be done in a separate query, after the desired new value holder is 'moved'.

So far I was doing this with:

```
//being n my new value.
UPDATE values SET val = val+1 WHERE val >= n
```

But this would also modify 7,8 and 9, which don't need to be modified.

Any thoughts about how to solve this part of the issue? Limiting the update to only the consecutive values?

A better way of doing the whole insert/update in one query would be also very appreciated.

Comment: You could renumber the values also when deleting single rows like `UPDATE values SET val = val-1 WHERE val >= n`. This way, you would always have consecutive numbers and could again use `UPDATE values SET val = val+1 WHERE val >= n`. Not optimal, but working.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but the source of the non-consecutiveness is  the user. This values are used as priorities, and the user can reassign the priority of a task, and assign a random priority to it in the range of 1 to 20.

Comment: If the `val` column has an actual `UNIQUE` constraint, then you might need `UPDATE ... ORDER BY`, which is unfortunately isn't compiled to SQLite by default. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution #1 with `LEFT JOIN`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7eeea/12

```
UPDATE t
SET val = val+1
WHERE val >= 2
  AND val <= (
    SELECT MIN(t1.val)
    FROM      t AS t1
    LEFT JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.val+1 = t2.val
    WHERE t1.val >= 2
      AND t2.val IS NULL
  );
```

Solution #2 with `NOT EXISTS`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7eeea/17

```
UPDATE t
SET val = val+1
WHERE val >= 2
  AND val <= (
        SELECT MIN(t1.val)
        FROM  t AS t1
        WHERE t1.val >= 2
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t AS t2 WHERE t1.val+1 = t2.val)
  );
```

Comment: Great answer, very well researched and I didn't know sqlfiddle. I'll say you need to cast any value to integer CAST(val AS INTEGER) in the comparison parts to make it work, at least in my case, since I had affinity set to STRING there. Your solutions work perfect, I personally go for the second one which is the one I understood how it works.

Comment: A little illustration for the first variation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7eeea/22 :)

Comment: +1 thank you very much! I finally applied this solutions to my overly-bloated query xD thanks again.

Comment: Your query is not bloated, these are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509947/how-can-i-optimize-this-query-produced-by-sqlalchemy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495516/magento-sql-query-help-needed-with-massive-query :)