# Magento sql query help needed with massive query

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, select

I'm trying to modify the following MySQL query for Magento. What it does now is returns product information for simple and configurable products for a report.
Unfortunately, the simple products don't have all the info that the parent configurable products have.

What I'd like it to do is use the table `catalog_product_super_link` to look up the parent product id of every product so that for all products, I'm getting the data of the parent configurable product. The super link table has the values for all product id's in one column, and the corresponding parent in another. For configurable products, the product id and parent id are the same.

Make sense?

The query I've got is:

```
SELECT IFNULL(category_name.value, category_default_name.value) AS `primarycategory`
     , `product`.`sku`
     , IFNULL(product_name.value, product_default_name.value) AS `product_name`
     , `attribute_option_value`.`value` AS `story`
     , (
         select GROUP_CONCAT(category_name.value)
         from catalog_category_entity as category
            , catalog_category_entity_varchar as category_name
            , catalog_category_product as category_product
         WHERE category_name.entity_id = category.entity_id
           AND category_name.store_id = 0
           AND category_name.entity_type_id = 3
           AND category_name.attribute_id = 33
           AND category_product.product_id = order_item.product_id
           AND category_product.category_id = category.entity_id
           AND category_name.value<>'Default Category'
       ) AS `category`
     , round(sum(order_item.qty_ordered)) AS `unitssoldnum`
     , ROUND(sum(order_item.price-order_item.discount_amount-order_item.tax_amount)
           , 2
       ) AS `unitssoldcur`
     , ROUND((
               SUM(order_item.price-order_item.discount_amount-order_item.tax_amount)
               - (IFNULL(product_cost.value, product_default_cost.value) * SUM(order_item.qty_ordered))
             )
           , 2
       ) AS `grossmargincur`
     , ROUND((
               (
                 SUM(order_item.price-order_item.discount_amount-order_item.tax_amount)
                 - (IFNULL(product_cost.value, product_default_cost.value) * SUM(order_item.qty_ordered))
               )
               / (SUM(order_item.price-order_item.discount_amount-order_item.tax_amount))
             )
             * 100
           , 2
       ) AS `grossmarginpercent`
     , (
         SELECT round(SUM(qty))
         FROM cataloginventory_stock_item AS stock
            , catalog_product_super_link AS product_link
         WHERE product_link.product_id = stock.product_id
           AND product_link.parent_id=order_item.product_id
       ) AS `sohatstore`
     , (
         SELECT round(SUM(qty)/SUM(order_item.qty_ordered))
         FROM cataloginventory_stock_item AS stock
            , catalog_product_super_link AS product_link
         WHERE product_link.product_id = stock.product_id
           AND product_link.parent_id=order_item.product_id
       ) AS `storecover`
     , (
         SELECT round(SUM(order_item.qty_ordered)
                      /(SUM(qty)+SUM(order_item.qty_ordered))
                      *100
                    , 2
                )
         FROM cataloginventory_stock_item AS stock
            , catalog_product_super_link AS product_link
         WHERE product_link.product_id = stock.product_id
           AND product_link.parent_id=order_item.product_id
       ) AS `sellthrupercent`
     , ROUND(SUM(order_item.price),2) AS `originalretail`
     , ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(product_cost.value, product_default_cost.value))
           , 2
       ) AS `costextax`
     , (
         SELECT round(SUM(qty_ordered))
         FROM sales_flat_order_item AS order_total
         WHERE order_total.product_id = order_item.product_id
       ) AS `totalsoldtilldate`
     , (
         SELECT ROUND((
                        SELECT round(SUM(qty_ordered))
                        FROM sales_flat_order_item AS order_total
                        WHERE order_total.product_id = order_item.product_id
                      )
                      /(
                        (
                          SELECT round(SUM(qty_ordered))
                          FROM sales_flat_order_item AS order_total
                          WHERE order_total.product_id = order_item.product_id
                        )
                        +(
                          SELECT round(SUM(qty))
                          FROM cataloginventory_stock_item AS stock
                             , catalog_product_super_link AS product_link
                          WHERE product_link.product_id = stock.product_id
                            AND product_link.parent_id=order_item.product_id
                        )
                      )*100
                    , 2
                )
       ) AS `totalsellthru`
     , (
         SELECT ROUND((
                        (
                          sum(order_total.price-order_total.discount_amount-order_total.tax_amount)
                          - sum(order_total.base_cost * order_total.qty_ordered)
                        )
                        /sum(order_total.price-order_total.discount_amount-order_total.tax_amount)
                      )*100
                    , 2
                )
         FROM sales_flat_order_item AS order_total
         WHERE order_total.product_id = order_item.product_id
       ) AS `totalgrossmarginpercent`
FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `order`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_item` ON order_item.order_id = order.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product`
    ON product.entity_id = order_item.product_id
   AND product.entity_type_id = 4
   AND product.type_id NOT IN('grouped', 'bundle')
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `product_name`
    ON product_name.entity_id = product.entity_id
   AND product_name.store_id = order.store_id
   AND product_name.entity_type_id = 4
   AND product_name.attribute_id = 60
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `product_default_name`
    ON product_default_name.entity_id = product.entity_id
   AND product_default_name.store_id = 0
   AND product_default_name.entity_type_id = 4
   AND product_default_name.attribute_id = 60
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `product_cost`
    ON product_cost.entity_id = product.entity_id
   AND product_cost.store_id = order.store_id
   AND product_cost.entity_type_id = 4
   AND product_cost.attribute_id = 68
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `product_default_cost`
    ON product_default_cost.entity_id = product.entity_id
   AND product_default_cost.store_id = 0
   AND product_default_cost.entity_type_id = 4
   AND product_default_cost.attribute_id = 68
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity` AS `category`
    ON category.entity_id =  (select MAX(category_id) from catalog_category_product where product_id = product.entity_id)
   AND category.entity_type_id = 3
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `category_name`
    ON category_name.entity_id = category.parent_id
   AND category_name.store_id = order.store_id
   AND category_name.entity_type_id = 3
   AND category_name.attribute_id = 33
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `category_default_name`
    ON category_default_name.entity_id = category.parent_id
   AND category_default_name.store_id = 0
   AND category_default_name.entity_type_id = 3
   AND category_default_name.attribute_id = 33
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `story_name`
    ON story_name.entity_id = product.entity_id
   AND story_name.store_id = 1
   AND story_name.entity_type_id = 4
   AND story_name.attribute_id = 138
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `story_default_name`
    ON story_default_name.entity_id = product.entity_id
   AND story_default_name.store_id = 0
   AND story_default_name.entity_type_id = 4
   AND story_default_name.attribute_id = 138
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `attribute_option`
    ON attribute_option.option_id = IFNULL(story_name.value, story_default_name.value)
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `attribute_option_value`
    ON attribute_option_value.option_id = attribute_option.option_id
   AND attribute_option_value.store_id = 0
WHERE (order.state <> 'canceled')
  AND (DATE(order.created_at) <= DATE('2012-07-03'))
  AND (DATE(order.created_at) >= DATE('2012-07-01'))
GROUP BY `product_name`
ORDER BY `category_name`.`value` ASC
       , `category_default_name`.`value` ASC
       , `product_name`.`value` ASC
       , `product_default_name`.`value` ASC
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated :)

Here's a sample of the output I get for configurable products:

```
"Category Name",Product,Name,Story,"Category Description","Units Sold (#)","Units Sold ($)","GM ($)","GM (%)","SOH at Store","Store Cover","Sell through %","Original Retail Price","Cost Ex Tax","Total Units Sold (#)","Total Sell Thru %","GM% Total"
Bottoms,31875,"Denim Babe Jean",DENIM,"Bottoms,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$59.84,$39.25,65.59,118,59,1.67,$68.00,$10.30,81,40.70,69.38
Bottoms,34475,"Diamante Rip Boot Leg Jean",DENIM,"Bottoms,SALE,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$29.92,-$7.56,-25.25,28,14,6.67,$34.00,$18.74,5,15.15,19.90
Bottoms,35853,"Embroidered Back Wide Leg Jean",DENIM,"Bottoms,SALE,Denim,Jeans,Wideleg Jean,Pants",2,$29.92,-$9.08,-30.35,11,6,15.38,$34.00,$19.50,22,66.67,23.93
Bottoms,34278,"Firecracker Bootleg Jean",DENIM,"Bottoms,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$59.84,$29.92,50.00,9,5,18.18,$68.00,$14.96,39,81.25,43.99
Bottoms,28450,"Glamourzon Jean","CHIC","Bottoms,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$59.84,$59.84,100.00,101,51,1.94,$68.00,$0.00,51,33.55,100.00
```

And here's a sample of what I get with simple products. Notice all the missing data. That's why for my report I want to look up the parent product id and use it's data.

```
"Category Name",Product,Name,Story,"Category Description","Units Sold (#)","Units Sold ($)","GM ($)","GM (%)","SOH at Store","Store Cover","Sell through %","Original Retail Price","Cost Ex Tax","Total Units Sold (#)","Total Sell Thru %","GM% Total"
Bottoms,2000004614430,"Denim Babe Jean - Dark Denim - 24",DENIM,"Bottoms,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$0.00,-$20.59,,,,,$0.00,$10.30,15,,
Bottoms,2000004901523,"Diamante Rip Boot Leg Jean - Black - 14",DENIM,"Bottoms,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$0.00,-$37.48,,,,,$0.00,$18.74,2,,
Bottoms,2000004883881,"Firecracker Bootleg Jean - Denim Dark - 16",DENIM,"Bottoms,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$0.00,-$29.92,,,,,$0.00,$14.96,9,,
Bottoms,2000004159955,"Glamourzon Jean - Dark Denim - 24","CHIC","Bottoms,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$0.00,$0.00,,,,,$0.00,$0.00,11,,
Bottoms,2005010849432,"Glamourzon Night Jean - Black - 28","CHIC","Bottoms,Denim,Jeans,Bootleg Jean,Pants",2,$0.00,-$32.80,,,,,$0.00,$16.40,7,,-68.82
```

I hope that answered your question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a sample dump of the lower level entry you want, with the corresponding parent and thus show what OTHER entries you want at the lower level.  I THINK I understand what you are looking for, but dont want to force my interpretation first.  -- like 4-5 records per table to get a sample understanding.

Answer (score 0):

we are doing some similar reports. What you need to do:

- Start from the simple product
- JOIN over catalog_product_super_link table on the configurable product
- In the SELECT part of the query, use IF => if the value of the simple product ist there, use it, otherwise use the value of the configurable product (or the other way round)

**Example**

```
SELECT
    o.increment_id,    
    oi.order_id,
    o.STATUS AS order_status,
    o.created_at,                  
    ROUND(SUM(IF(oi2.qty_ordered IS NOT NULL, IF(oi2.qty_ordered > oi.qty_ordered, oi2.qty_ordered, oi.qty_ordered), oi.qty_ordered)), 0) AS cqty_ordered,
    ROUND(SUM(IF(oi2.qty_canceled IS NOT NULL, IF(oi2.qty_canceled > oi.qty_canceled, oi2.qty_canceled, oi.qty_canceled), oi.qty_canceled)), 0) AS cqty_canceled,
    ROUND(SUM(IF(oi2.qty_shipped IS NOT NULL, IF(oi2.qty_shipped > oi.qty_shipped, oi2.qty_shipped, oi.qty_shipped), oi.qty_shipped)), 0) AS cqty_shipped,
    ROUND(SUM(IF(oi2.qty_ordered IS NOT NULL, IF(oi2.qty_ordered > oi.qty_ordered, oi2.qty_ordered, oi.qty_ordered), oi.qty_ordered)) - SUM(IF(oi2.qty_canceled IS NOT NULL, IF(oi2.qty_canceled > oi.qty_canceled, oi2.qty_canceled, oi.qty_canceled), oi.qty_canceled)) - SUM(IF(oi2.qty_shipped IS NOT NULL, IF(oi2.qty_shipped > oi.qty_shipped, oi2.qty_shipped, oi.qty_shipped), oi.qty_shipped)), 0) AS cqty_missing
FROM sales_flat_order_item AS oi
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order AS o ON oi.order_id=o.entity_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS oi2 ON oi.parent_item_id=oi2.item_id AND oi2.product_type='configurable'
WHERE oi.product_type='simple'
GROUP BY oi.order_id
HAVING cqty_missing=0 AND order_status NOT IN ('complete','canceled','closed');
```